# How can I update product categories using prestashop web service?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hi I want to remotely update all the "attributes" related with a product using prestashop web service. I have been trying to update its categories for days unsuccessfully. I am using prestashop_1.6.1.5.
Following the [doc](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Chapter+5+-+Data+modification+-+Updating+a+customer) you can get a product xml like this

```
$xml = $this->webService->get(array('url' => 'http://prestashop.localhost/api/products/2'));

var_dump($xml);

$resources = $xml->children()->children();
```

Then if you do

```
$resources->reference = "NEW REFERENCE";
```

and you can modify the reference, for example.

It is possible to view its categories by

```
$resources->associations->categories->categories
```

You will get the array of category ids that are related with the product. But if you do:

```
$resources->associations->categories->categories[2] = 8
```

You will not update the third category associated to the product to 8. It will remain like 0.
I have also tried to assing it a string. I have tried to unset the whole categories node, create my own node with the same format it uses and after that, assing it again. I have tried also creating a SimpleXMlElement and adding it with addChild() for each id I want to modify. But nothing worked.

Does anybody knows how to update categories?

I have also another question, what is the difference between these category ids and the default_category_id that appears in product xml? If you see prestashop DDBB the default_category_id does not appear in the intermediate table. I mean If the default_category_id is 9, the other ids are 2,3,4 and 7 in the example products you have when you start using prestashop.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Categories can be updated like this:

```
$id_product = 102;
$new_product_categories = array(29,30,31); // List of categories to be linked to product

$xml = $this->webservice->get(array('resource' => 'products', 'id' => $id_product));

$product = $xml->children()->children();

// Unset fields that may not be updated
unset($product->manufacturer_name);
unset($product->quantity);

// Remove current categories
unset($product->associations->categories); 

// Create new categories
$categories = $product->associations->addChild('categories'); 

foreach ($new_product_categories as $id_category) {
    $category = $categories->addChild('category');
    $category->addChild('id', $id_category);
}

$xml_response = $this->webservice->edit(array('resource' => 'products', 'id' => $id_product, 'putXml' => $xml->asXML()));
```

Comment: I have used this code it is working for single update, but when I add this for update multiple product getting issue like HTTP XML response is not parsable: array ( 0 => LibXMLError::__set_state(array( 'level' => 3, 'code' => 64, 'column' => 6, 'message' => 'XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document ', 'file' => '', 'line' => 2, )), )